# Regex word boundary: <|wb> v. <?wb>

Tags: raku

**Edit: @ikegami was the first person to respond and pointed out my typo.**

The raku [Regex docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Word_boundary) say:

> To match any word boundary, use <|w> or <?wb>. This is similar to \b in other languages.

This is what I'm seeing in rakudo:

```
[309] > "apa pz" ~~ / <|wb> p. /
｢pa｣

[310] > "apa pz" ~~ / <?wb> p. /
｢pz｣
```

`<?wb>` behaves the way I would expect.  What is `<|wb>` doing?

In perl:

```
"apa pz" =~ / \b p. /xms;  
say $&;   # pz
```

Comment: Okay, the docs say _"To match any word boundary, use <|w> or <?wb>."_ So we can agree that `<|wb>` is erroneous syntax?

Comment: @jubilatious1,  Yes, @ikegami was the first one to solve my problem, but then he/she deleted their comment.  I was going to delete my question, but @codesections elaborated that `<|w>` shouldn't even be mentioned in the docs because it's not part of rakudo--even though it works the same as `<?wb>`.  I didn't want that useful information to be deleted, so here we are.

Comment: Advertising a regex idiom like `<|w>` on the https://docs.raku.org page means that Rakuuns hold _some_ responsibility for making sure that it works in end-users (i.e. __your__) hands. Besides, we agree that `<|wb>` should throw an error, correct?

Comment: @jubilatious1, Yes.

Comment: @raiph, `<|wb>` is not in the Regexes > [Word Boundary](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Word_boundary) docs, which is what I was reading.  `<|wb>` is my typo.  The Regexes > Word Boundary docs say: *To match any word boundary, use <|w> or <?wb>.*

Comment: Ohhh. My eyesight is failing! When I skimmed the doc I misread `<!wb>`  as `<|wb>`.

Comment: @7stud Having finally twigged what was happening in this SO I went to delete my answer -- but then realized I'd linked to it from the doc issue. So we've arrived at the unfortunate outcome that your Q is much ado about not a lot yet has three answers with no sense of closure. I get, and agree with, why you haven't *deleted* your Q, but maybe you can accept .@codesections' answer and/or we can *close* your Q instead to signal "These are not the droids you're looking for" to later searchers?

Answer (score 6):

`<?wb>` does what you want. `<|wb>` and `<|w>` are both, IIUC, unsupported syntax that should throw an error.  And, indeed, they both do using the soon-to-be-released Raku AST compiler frontend:

```bash
$ RAKUDO_RAKUAST=1 raku -e 'say "apa pz" ~~ / <|w> p. /'
> ===SORRY!===
> Cannot find method 'apply-sink' on object of type NQPMu
```

More officially, no regex syntax starting with `<|` is spec'ed in Roast (Raku's test suite/specification).

(This means, of course, that it's an error for the docs to refer to `<|w>` syntax; I submitted a [PR with a fix](https://github.com/Raku/doc/pull/4435)).

Comment: `IIUC`: First hit on google -> International Islamic University Chittagong.  Were you stating your educational background in support of your answer?

Comment: Personally, I prefer `<|w>`.  The syntax `<?wb>` looks like it's optional.

Comment: @7stud If I Understand Correctly. Or was this a joke?

Comment: @7stud the forms `<?before ... >` (positive lookahead) and `<?after ... >` (positive lookbehind) are a welcome idiom in Raku. Maybe `<?wb>` will catch your fancy after a while? See also `<!wb>` compared to `<!before ... >` (negative lookahead) and `<!after ... >` (negative lookbehind). Thx.

Comment: "`<|wb>` and `<|w>` are both, IIUC, unsupported syntax" From the roast perspective I agree. "they both [throw an error] using the soon-to-be-released Raku AST" I very much welcome a mass clearing up of loose ends that RAST can help force, with a general bias toward decisions that simplify, or at least floating trial balloons of such decisions, to see if the community can stomach leaving a bunch of unofficial stuff behind to shrink the workload to ship an officially done RAST. After all, we can (re)introduce stuff later. That said, I think I see merit in `<|w>` et al long term so would keep it.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** `<|wb>` is a typo.¹ If you're trying to figure out some raku feature, [design.raku.org](https://design.raku.org) is a key resource.²˒³

## S05: Regexes and rules

I pulled up [S05: Regexes and rules](https://github.com/Raku/old-design-docs/blob/master/S05-regex.pod) and did an in-page search for  `<|`⁴. [The first match](https://github.com/Raku/old-design-docs/blob/a4c36c683dafdad0bb55996e78b66a1f48fc703c/S05-regex.pod#L1978-L1984) nailed it:

> A leading `|` [in an assertion, ie starting with a `<` and ending with a `>`] indicates some kind of a zero-width boundary. You can refer to backslash sequences with this syntax; `<|h>` will match between a `\h` and a `\H`, for instance. Some examples:
>
> - `<|w>` word boundary
> - `<|g>` grapheme boundary (always matches in grapheme mode)
> - `<|c>` codepoint boundary (always matches in grapheme/codepoint mode)

I hope you can see why this instantly suggested to me a simple explanation: the syntax is (presumably) for use with a single character backslash sequence (eg `\w`, but not `\wb`).⁵

## Footnotes

¹ I suspect <strike>they</strike> you wrote `<|wb>` because you were confusing `<|w>` with the `<wb>` assertion.

² By "spec" I mean "speculation" about "specification". The design documents were, and to a degree still are, *authoritative* about our evolution *toward* many current and future Raku features. We may have gone another route, or not yet gotten to where the "spec" pointed, but they're a key resource for understanding Raku's design.

³ Another key resource is [the Raku project's IRC logs home](https://irclogs.raku.org/home.html). Discussion of Raku's design has been happening on IRC, and logged, since early 2005. TimToady (Larry Wall) comments, and bot logging of design doc commits, are often golden.

⁴ The  `<|` search string has an initial space. (Otherwise you'll get a boatload of irrelevant matches instead because the source is written in RakuDoc.)

⁵ I checked a somewhat recent Rakudo and it didn't implement `<|h>`. And there's no support for `\g` or `\c` backslash sequences, so they're out too. Unless and until someone does the corresponding implementation work, the "specs" are, first and foremost, speculation.

Answer (score 2):

**Seems to be a difference between `<|w>` (specc'ed?) and `<|wb>` (not specc'ed?):**

```perl
% raku
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2023.05.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2023.05.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
[0] > "apa pz" ~~ / <|wb> p. /
｢pa｣
[1] > "apa pz" ~~ / <|w> p. /
｢pz｣
```

The docs say: *"To match any word boundary, use `<|w>` or `<?wb>`."* I don't see `<|wb>` mentioned on that page (first link at bottom). But maybe it has been edited away?

The only guess I can venture is that somehow `<|wb` is mis-interpreted as a quoted list. See second link at bottom.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Word_boundary
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Quoted_lists_are_LTM_matches